# Error when an agg pipeline assigns a value to the $$Maincode builtin variable

Tags: c#, mongodb, pipeline

```
   var lookup = 
                        new BsonDocument("$lookup",
                        new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {"from","DepoStatus" },
                            {"let",new BsonDocument{ {Maincode,"$Maincode"},{ColorCode , "$Renkcode" } } },
                            {"pipeline",
                                new BsonArray{
                                    new BsonDocument("$match",
                                    new BsonDocument("$expr",
                                    new BsonDocument("$and",
                                      new BsonArray{new BsonDocument("$eq",
                                      new BsonArray { "$Maincode", "$$Maincode" }),new BsonDocument("$eq", new BsonArray { "$Renkcode", "$$Renkcode" })}))),
                                }
                            },
                            {"as","statuses"}
                        });
                   
                    var pipeline1 = new[] { lookup };
                    var depostatus = czProductcollection.Aggregate<Product>(pipeline1).ToList();
```

MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command aggregate failed: '20.296' starts with an invalid character for a user variable name.'
I get an error. What can I do ?

Comment: user variables, cannot start with capital letter, `Maincode` and `ColorCode` for example.
system variables like `$$ROOT` have capitals. change the name to lower-case and you will be fine i think

Comment: I did but my problem still persists. Am I typing the pipeline coding wrong?

Comment: You are using variables only in 1 place `{"let",new BsonDocument{ {Maincode,"$Maincode"},{ColorCode , "$Renkcode" } } }` , i think you should replace Maincode with "maincode" (lower-case + string) , and ColorCode the same